Can anybody tell me who's artist seal this is? (Characters identified: 九峰山人)
I have bought 2 chinese paintings but i can't find who this artist is. Does anybody know who's seal this is and if it is valuable?
Also, any info about the date when these paintings were created is very welcome!




九峰山人 is the name of the artist. These appear to be modern painting. The first depicts the God of Longevity. The second painting is based on a Chinese legend of the Waring States period, when the King of Qi went to recruit a famous wise man, who was said to be already over 80 and enjoyed fishing everyday by a creek outside of his home.
I'm not sure about how much you paid for them. They are definitely not antiques.
